# How to convert old mysql to pdo

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to convert my mysql code to the new pdo codes i really need some help since the mysql is depreciated. I`m new to php and mysql, need a good example to follow on. thanks for any help i get.

Old MSYQL

```
<?php
include_once("Connections/database.php");
$login = $_SESSION['login'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proryniti_members WHERE email='".$login."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
    die("member not found!");
else
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $firstName = $row['firstName'];
    $lastName = $row['lastName'];
}

?>
```

PDO code

```
<?php
include_once("Connections/database.php");
$login = $_SESSION['login'];

$qry = $dbh->prepare(
  'SELECT * FROM proryniti_members WHERE email = :'.$login.'');
$qry->execute(array($login));
$row = $qry->fetch();
if (!is_null($row)) {
    $firstName = $row['firstName'];
    $lastName = $row['lastName'];
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You did not understand how prepared queries work in PDO. I suggest you go back to reading the documentation or the examples on the net. I modified your code above, take a look at lines 6-5.:

```
 <?php
   include_once("Connections/database.php");
  $login = $_SESSION['login'];

  $qry = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM proryniti_members WHERE email=:login');
  $qry->execute(array(':login'=>$login));
  $row = $qry->fetch();
  if (!is_null($row)) {
  $firstName = $row['firstName'];
  $lastName = $row['lastName'];
  } 
  ?>
```

Comment: -1 for 'Go back to the documentation'. If every answer on StackOverflow was just 'RTFM', the site wouldn't be much use.

Comment: @monkeymatrix: Certainly true. But my answer isn't "just" RTFM, or is it? And certainly reading the documentation is neccessary in this case. I'd say this site would be less flooded if people would _first_ read the documentation and post question only if that did not solve their issue.

Comment: Documentation is usually written in an absolutely bizarre way most of the time. I'd rather have an explanation from regular human beings.

Comment: What you saying is true but just once in a while. For example, the Android docs are much more clear (and sometimes with really good examples) when iOS is written by someone from a different planet. When it comes to iOS I hardly ever get any help from official docs so the only option is StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: Well, the sense is simple... If someone has time and the ability to rephrase the official documentation and add some examples (like you did by the way) it's better to do that rather than advising people to go back and read the official docs. And that's what this website is all about I think. Not everyone is an experienced developer. I personally wouldn't be able to do anything without the help and explanation of everyone who's here. But anyway, this is not the right place for arguments. Nothing personal.